Android Studio: how to Gradle Sync then Run in one click/shortcut
Everytime I modify build.gradle, a Sync Now button/link appears at the top of the editor pane, and the Run button (green arrow) becomes grayed out.
So to run the app I need to click Sync Now, wait for it to complete, then click the Run button.
How can I perform both actions in only one step?
